# add marker on polyline due various distances of polyline in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet project with a polyline on the map. Now I was able to calculate the distance between the points of the polyline. But how can I add markers by distance between these points?

Comment: Why don't you watch the quick start? http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/ And please leave an example of your problem for easy understanding.

Comment: i found a decision. If we have a straight AB, with point M in it. We can find M coordinates, using that formula: Mx = (Ax +(AM length / MB length) * Bx) / 1 + (AM length / MB length), and My = (Ay +(AM length / MB length) * By) / 1 + (AM length / MB length)

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [leaflet-distance-markers](https://github.com/adoroszlai/leaflet-distance-markers) plugin:

> Allows displaying markers along a route (L.Polyline) at equivalent distances (eg. one per mile)

See the [demo](http://adoroszlai.github.io/leaflet-distance-markers/).

You can also look for other Leaflet [plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html).