# Leaflet - Add marker at specific distance along polyline

Tags: leaflet, maps

I'm working on a leaflet based map and would like to add a marker at a specific distance along a polyline.

I've seen and made work something similar ([add marker on polyline due various distances of polyline in leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40414092/add-marker-on-polyline-due-various-distances-of-polyline-in-leaflet)) that places distance markers along the whole route/polyline - but I only need to show a single marker.

Here's the section of code that I think I need to update, but not sure what?

thanks in advance :-)

```
    //  coords (from gpx)
        var coords = 
            [
                [58.64385, -3.02631],[58.64385, -3.02631],[58.64359, -3.0291],[58.64375, -3.03169],[58.64368, -3.0321],[58.64355, -3.03239],[58.64327, -3.03267]
            ]

    // polyline
        var polyline = L.polyline(coords, {
            distanceMarkers: { offset: 1600, iconSize: [20, 20] }
        });


    // zoom the map to the route
        map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
        map.addLayer(polyline);
```

Comment: https://turfjs.org/docs/#along

Comment: Thanks - that's a great toolset. A little daunting to follow, but it works. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

this is how I made it work with Turf.fs

```
        var line = turf.lineString(somePoints);
        var options = {units: 'miles'};
        L.geoJSON(line).addTo(map);
        
        var along = turf.along(line, 1.25, options);
            L.geoJSON(along).addTo(map).bindTooltip("my tooltip text");
         
            along = turf.along(line, 2.123, options);
            L.geoJSON(along).addTo(map).bindTooltip("12345");
```